# How to connect to GoInstant twice on the same page?

Tags: javascript, goinstant

This is the basic structure of my code:

```
var url = "https://goinstant.net/Something/SomethingElse";
goinstant.connect(url, function (err, connection, lobby) {
  var something = lobby.key("something");
  // and also some other stuff
});
```

And then later, in a different script document, but still on the same page:

```
var url = "https://goinstant.net/Something/SomethingElse";
goinstant.connect(url, function (err, connection, lobby) {
  var something = lobby.key("something");
  // and also some other stuff
});
```

The basic exact same deal. Except now Google Chrome is giving me these errors:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://goinstant.net/engine.io/?acct=Something&app=SomethingElse&jwt=UtAhSf3vmpLNcT0…6MDbfhLZN3G4jNqmMQQjlnl&EIO=2&transport=websocket&sid=9yQO6vVBI1syXlsxAAhJ' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established. platform.min.js:3
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'key' of undefined
```

How do I fix this? I remove the second bit of code, and everything works fine.

**UPDATE:** So now I'm using the approved answer's code:

```
var url = "https://goinstant.net/Something/SomethingElse";
var opts = {sessionId: "", guestId: ""};
goinstant.connect(url, opts, function (err, connection, lobby) {
  var something = lobby.key("something");
  // and also some other stuff
});
```

But for some reason, it is still not working. It is showing the same errors, and one more about some kind of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` trying to go to GoInstant's servers via http.

**ANOTHER UPDATE:** I copied the answer's code, and then it seemed to work fine. But what I did was this:

I opened around 20 Google Chrome tabs, all with the same test page.

The first 5 worked, and the last 15 didn't, with the same websocket error as before, and also something about `key not defined`.

I know I'm starting to be a nuisance, but how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the undocumented `sessionId` and `guestId` properties on the [optionsObject parameter](https://developers.goinstant.com/v1/javascript_api/connect.html#parameters) of `goinstant.connect':

```
var url = "https://goinstant.net/ACCOUNT/APPLICATION";
var opts = {sessionId: null, guestId: null};

var conn1, lobby1, conn2, lobby2;

goinstant.connect(url, opts, function(err, connection, lobby) {
  conn1 = connection;
  lobby1 = lobby;

  lobby.key('conn2Key').on('set', function(value, context) {
    console.log('-----------------------');
    console.log('Saw a set on conn2Key');
    console.log('User:', context.userId);
    console.log('Value:', value);
    console.log('This connection is user:', lobby.self().name.split('/')[2]);
    console.log('-----------------------');
  });
});

goinstant.connect(url, opts, function(err, connection, lobby) {
  conn2 = connection;
  lobby2 = lobby;

  setTimeout(function() {
    lobby.key('conn2Key').set('Hi!');
  }, 1000);
});
```

When set to an empty string or `null`, the connection will generate a new guest user and session for the connection.

By default, guest user information within a GoInstant application is shared across tabs, and sessions are reused within tabs (so if you reload, you can properly reconnect). This is why using two instances breaks; the same `sessionId` attempts to connect twice.

This feature is undocumented and unsupported, so it may change or break in the future.

Comment: Beautiful answer. Comes in handy for me as well.

Comment: Undocumented no longer!

Comment: @secretmike Then where is it documented?

Comment: For some reason, it is still showing the error. Where did I get this wrong?

Comment: @think123 it's not officially documented. I believe secretmike was referring to the fact that it has been discussed publicly now. If you have any further issues, share your code and we can help further.

Comment: @JeffAndersen I shared what I've got now in the answer.

Comment: goinstant.connect doesn't like running in parallel with itself. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: connecting in parallel now works. I've updated the example for this.

Comment: what is the use of storing the connection and lobby in variables?

Comment: it seems it's still not working, when I open heaps of tabs in one go. Check my question again please.

Comment: There's a limit of 20 users per room. With 2 connections per tab and only 5 tabs working, the math doesn't add up exactly, but maybe you are hitting the limit? check if `err` is not null, and see what `err.message` is. It should say if you have hit the limit.

Comment: Yeah, it gives me `room is full`. How would I fix that?

Comment: @think123 I'll send you an email about it :) And you are certainly not a nuisance!